# Sprache: parse signed integer

Tags: c#, parsing, integer, sprache

I wonder if there is a better way to parse signed integer using [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/sprache) parser framework.

There is well known parser definition for integers without sign
`Parse.Number.Select(int.Parse)`

But I want to parse integers with `-` prefix as well.

What I have got right now is `Parse.Regex(@"\-?\d+").Select(int.Parse)`.

Is there a better way to do that without using regular expressions?

For example use `Parse.Char('-').Optional()` and then parse following number.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I do this is similar to the following:

```
from op in Parse.Optional(Parse.Char('-').Token())
from num in Parse.Decimal
from trailingSpaces in Parse.Char(' ').Many()
select decimal.Parse(num) * (op.IsDefined ? -1 : 1);
```

Of course, leave out the trailingSpaces portion depending on the context of what you're parsing.

Comment: Thank you @Geoff. That is (probably) what I was looking for. But... now I am meditate :) - whether your given method is "better" than mine... It is much longer and I'd say harder to read if you don't know Sprache well. Anyway, thanks. +1

Comment: Sure thing - and I know what you mean about being harder to read if you don't use Sprache very often.  On the other hand, I don't use regular expressions very often, and I find "\-?\d+" quite non-intuitive!

Comment: For the second line why not replace it with Parse.Number.Select(int.Parse)? Also, add '+' in?.

Comment: Also, Geoff, is there any particular reason you are parsing whitespace there?

Comment: @Gordon - Both the `Parse.Decimal` and the whitespace handling are there because I extracted the code from a parser project that required handling of decimals - but `Parse.Number` would work too.  I leave the select to the end as it's easy to gather up the pieces found and deal with it all in one chunk; in the actual code I was instantiating a class instead, i.e. `select new DecimalExpression(...)`